# Настройка visual studio code. Префиксы переменным

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Как задать OmniSharp правила именования переменных? Хочу к автоматически создаваемым приватным полям добавлять префикс `_`. К примеру, при вызове быстрых действий на параметре конструктора.